# Vagrant box for vmware provider

Tags: vmware, vagrant

Not too sure where this should be asked. If irrelevant please redirect.

I'm wondering why all the Ubuntu boxes on VagrantCloud are targeted at virtualbox.

I need one tailored for the vagrant vmware provider.

The problem is that the vagrant boxes available from Ubuntu on VagrantCloud are specifically targeted at virtualbox, and as such can't be used with the vmware provider. What I'm trying to find out is who's maintaining those vagrant boxes, as they seem to be officialy released by Ubuntu: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu

For example, look at this vagrant box. It is specifically advertised as an "official" Ubuntu cloud image, so I'd like to find out who maintains those images: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64

Who's responsible for those boxes ? Who should be contacted for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the vagrant boxes are build for virtualBox, because by default, vagrant is configured to use virtualBox as its provider. Moreover virtualBox is free of charge where that isn't the case with other providers. I can't find any good reason on why we should use other providers. I use vagrant for most of my projects both on LAMP and MEAN and using virtualBox without any problems.

Now you want to use vmware, you have to install plugins. You can always build a box from scratch if you don't get one from cloud. But of course, that is a time consuming process. I've published a guide on ['how to setup a ubuntu development environment using vagrant'](http://jasnan.github.io/developers-guide-to-setting-up-ubutnu-for-web-development/) and in that I have mentioned how to wrap an existing vagrant environment in to a new box. Again, I'm not sure if repackaging is possible for another provider. Please check it out and let us know about it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question it is probably the Ubuntu Cloud Images team that creates these boxes automatically using a tool like Packer (at packer.io) or a custom workflow that generates a compatible Vagrant box. As stated by Jasnan these are easiest and cheapest to do via Virtualbox because there is ZERO licensing costs and users who are cheap are far more likely to use Virtualbox than VMware which runs around $200, and the Vagrant plugin that is required to use it with VMware is another $79, so a user who is $280 in is probably likely to have their own preferences on which box to use and they are probably happy with one of the many other Ubuntu based images available.

Here is the root of the Ubuntu cloud images repository for Docker/Vagrant and other platforms.
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/

If you would like to build your own there are any examples available for Packer like the following Github repository.
https://github.com/boxcutter/ubuntu